# How to set the IP Address of a Virtualbox guest manually

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

For sake of automation I need to be able to manually set the IP address of my Virtualbox guest (which is an OS X) to a fixed IP.

Can this be done using VBoxManage? I need to avoid the GUI.

Thanks

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=38879)

Answer (score 2):

in your virtual machine setting, you can find networking adapters. You have some choice :

Network Address Translation (NAT): Used to share the host's IP address
If all you want is to browse the Web, download files and view e-mail inside the guest, then this default mode should be sufficient for you, and you can safely skip the rest of this section.

Bridged networking
This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations and running servers in a guest. When enabled, VirtualBox connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack.

Host-only networking
This can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among virtual machines and the host.

if you want specific IP for your virtual machine you can set in your guest vm ( ifconfig in linux & ipconfig in windows) and choose NAT in network adapter setting .

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html